# Trouble with inheritance and extending framework classes

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a custom class C inheriting UIView in which I defined some common methods.

Now I want a UITextView object A and a UIView object B to have those methods. For B, I just need to change his father to C.

But what should I do to A? I cannot directly change its father to C because otherwise I will lose UITextView's methods.

Also I cannot(and don't want to) use category, because in C I have some properties and member variables.

Comment: Categories and single inheritance are the tools.  We'd need to look at specifics to see how else you might accomplish your goal.  But there's no other inheritance-like alternative, if that's what you're hoping for.

Answer (score 1):

Multiple inheritance is not a feature in Objective-C.  At best, you can have both your UITextView subclass and your UIView subclass implement a common protocol. Of course, that will mean you would have to duplicate code.

I believe you *can* achieve the effect you desire with categories.  You can add properties at runtime leveraging objc/runtime.h (borrowed from [NSHipster](http://nshipster.com/reader-submissions-new-years-2013/))

```
#import "UIView+MyView.h"
#import <objc/runtime.h>

static const void *IndieBandNameKey = &IndieBandNameKey;    

@implementation UIView (MyView)
@dynamic indieBandName;

- (NSString *)indieBandName {
    return objc_getAssociatedObject(self, IndieBandNameKey);
}

- (void)setIndieBandName:(NSString *)indieBandName {
    objc_setAssociatedObject(self, IndieBandNameKey, indieBandName, OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN_NONATOMIC);
}

@end
```

Because UITextView is a subclass of UIView, methods you put into a UIView category will apply to your UIView subclass as well as your UITextView subclass. Additionally, you'll also be able to access these dynamically created properties in your category methods, allowing you to leverage those "member variables" you've now declared.